# Upload Large Video File on server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I want to upload large video file on server.I have a code that works fine for small videos but  even 30 seconds video are also not uploaded.I have increased the timeOutSeconds also but that also of no use.

strurl contains the path of the video file.

Here's the code:-

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/uploadVideo.php",appUrl];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];                      
[request setPostValue:self.gameID forKey:@"gameId"];                    
[request setFile:strurl forKey:@"uploadfile"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:1000];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
NSLog(@"responseString %@",[request responseString]);
```

Please help me
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try [NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBodyStream:fileStream]?

Comment: check your php configuration for post_max_size. May be uploadVideo.php file doesnt allow you to upload big sizes.

Comment: @alkimake I have checked that the php is fine.

Comment: As Vincent G hints at, for us to have any chance of helping you really need to describe exactly how it is failing - does the request complete? If it does is there an error, and if so what? and so on - any information might help.